# как присвоить istream ссылке?

Tags: c++

Сформулировать вопрос лучше не смог. Поясню на примере

```
class A{
  A(istream &in);
  ...
}

int main(){
 istream in;
 auto file = std::ifstream("test.file");
 if(file) in = file;
 else in = std::cin;
 A a(in);
}
```

Данный код закономерно не работает так как конструктор копирования в issream нет. Как можно передать параметр в конструктор?

Comment: `A a{file ? static_cast<::std::istream &>(file) : static_cast<::std::istream &>(::std::cin)};`

Comment: in нужно не присваивать, а **инициализировать**.

Comment: Harry а как можно инициализировать класс под if-фом. user7860670 спасибо, это гениально

Comment: Да именно так и инициализировать... `istream& in = (file) ? file : cin;`

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, спасибо user7860670

```
int main(){
 auto file = std::ifstream("test.file");
 A a{file ? static_cast<::std::istream &>(file) : static_cast<::std::istream &>(::std::cin)};;
}
```